# reticulate won't find conda env on Linux

Tags: python, r, reticulate

This is driving me crazy:

```
root@1f248ca02fb8:/# which python
/miniconda/bin/python
```

But then

```
root@1f248ca02fb8:/# Rscript -e 'library(reticulate); py_config()'
Error: Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
Use reticulate::install_miniconda() if you'd like to install a Miniconda Python environment.
Execution halted
```

Why cant reticulate find miniconda?

UPDATE

This also did no help:

```
root@1f248ca02fb8:/# Rscript -e 'library(reticulate); use_miniconda("/miniconda/bin/python", required=T); py_config()'Error in use_miniconda("/miniconda/bin/python", required = T) : 
Miniconda is not installed.
Use reticulate::install_miniconda() to install Miniconda.
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid this error, you just need to tell `reticulate` which environment to use.

For normal Python:
Just add `use_python("/usr/bin/python", required=T)` to your code.

For miniconda:

```
use_miniconda("/miniconda/bin/python", required = T)
```

Or another path to a python binary. Also normal conda or another environment is possible. Check in the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/use_python.html#configure-which-version-of-python-to-use) then

Comment: @coulminer since i'm not experienced with miniconde, did you try it with `use_python` too?

Comment: yep I did @mischva11, did not help either. In the end I gave up, removed miniconda installation and installed it again explicitly via 'install_miniconda()' and it worked. Actually this all happened in a Dockerfile, so maybe I had misconfigured miniconda installation.